# In Ruby, can I access a class instance variable from within an instance method?

Tags: ruby, class, instance

The following code sets a class variable in the class `C` from a class method, and shows that it is accessible from an instance method:

```
class C
  def self.set_a
    @@a = 1
  end

  def get_a
    @@a
  end
end

C.set_a
C.new.get_a #=> 1
```

If I replace `@@a` in the class method `set_a` with `@a`, so that it creates a class instance variable instead of a class variable, can I still access it from within the instance method `get_a`?

Comment: I assume you know that you can't write `def get_a; @a; end`, as `c = C.new; c.get_a` would return the value of `c`'s instance_variable `@a`. You therefore will need to employ two methods within `get_a` to obtain the value of the class instance variable `@a`. The first to obtain `c`'s class; the second, invoked on `c`'s class, to obtain the value of the variable.

Comment: Instance variables belong to instances. That's why they are called instance variables. `C` and `C.new` are two completely different objects that have absolutely northing to do with each other. The whole point of instance variables is that one object cannot access another object's instance variables, *unless* that object explicitly exposes them in some manner.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can reference it directly. Class is an object and instance variables are private/internal to the object. You can access it either using [`instance_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) on the class or by wrapping it in a getter method.

In Rails you can use [`class_variable` macro](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html#method-i-class_attribute) that facilitates setting and accessing class-level variables.

Comment: What do you mean you can't reference it directly? Is not `instance_variable_get` a perfectly good, garden-variety method? I think you should say "yes, use `instance_variable_get`".

Comment: I mean that you cannot reference them using `@@var` or `@var` form, you need to  use a method to access it.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but the OP merely says, "...can I still access it from within the instance method get_a?". There's no mention of not using a method. Also, the mention of an accessor is somewhat irrelevant as it would seem that the OP only wants to change `get_a` and even if there were an accessor, you'd still be using a method in `get_a` to access it. This is of course a minor points.

Comment: @CarySwoveland in that sense almost all variables are accessible from everywhere (the only exception being local variables). With `class_eval` `instance_eval` and `send` you can bypass any scope restrictions, even if there isn't a standard interface in place like `instance_variable_get`